# Google Map browser version warning

Tags: gmlib

How do i remove this message on the google map:

"You are using a browser that is not supported by the Google Maps JavaScript API. Consider changing your browser."

Thanks for the help

Comment: By using a different browser, like it says in the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this appeared suddenly a few days ago.

I checked the megademo and saw that this program doesn’t show the error.

Here my solution: Search for 'ControlIEVersion' in the MegaDemo Project that is installed with the gmLib, and add this procedure to your application then call it in the form create of your application. Or set the required registry key value manually.

GMMap.Active := true;
  ControlIEVersion;

Regards Henry

Comment: I removed //ControlIEVersion; from MegaDemo and the message don´t appear in megademo map. Placing ControlIEVersion in my project after "GmMap.Active  := True" did not remove the message. How you did?